# Volver a tener la imagen original de un ImageView cuando vuelves a pulsar sobre el

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, image-view

¡Hola! Estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio con Kotlin y intento que cuando pulses en un ImageView cambie la imagen a otra, pero el problema es que al volver pulsar en el mismo ImageView no cambia a la imagen que tenia originalmente.

Este es mi código:

```
imagen.setOnClickListener {
    
   if (imagen.isPressed){
      imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2)
   }
   else {
      imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen)
   }
    
}
```

Se que ahí solo hago cambiar el ImageView una vez pero no sé como hacer que vuelva a tener la imagen original. He probado con varias opciones pero me da error, ¿hay alguna forma para ello?, ¡gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando una variable auxilar debería servirte.

Principalmente, el problema aquí se debe a que siempre vas a presionar la imagen. Por ese mismo motivo no te entra en la sentencia `else`.

```
int x = 0;
imagen.setOnClickListener {
    
   if (imagen.isPressed && x == 0){
      imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen2)
      x += 1;
   }
   else {
      imagen.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagen)
      x -= 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: Cuando testees el código escribe un comentario si este te funcione y te adjunto una breve explicación. No he tenido tiempo para comprobar si este funciona o no pero debería funcionarte ;)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado la ayuda con la variable externa, entiendo lo que hace pero jamás se me fuera ocurrido usar la variable externa jaja.

¡Muchas gracias!